# could not find this command '--andriod-licenses'

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

After trying many attempts like update sdk manager and their tools still i have getting this problem
dont know why my system is not find this command so that i can accept this licenses and remove the error from flutter doctor please help!

here are the images and my tools i installed :-
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3EJa.png)
[Sdk Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTkXJ.png)

watched every video on youtube but not a 1 video helped me all are just accept licenses and done.
Please tell me anyone how to [update/accept] andriod licenses from local directory so that i try and also their file.

Comment: watch uploaded image for better understanding the error

Comment: You have spelled the option wrong. It is supposed to be --android-licenses

Comment: Also see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled '--andr**oi**d-licenses' ;)

Comment: after this i get this error :- JAVA_HOME is set an invalid diresctory ; c:\program files\java\jdk-18.0.2.1\bin   please set the java-home variable in your environment to match the location of java installaation

Comment: You don't need `bin` at the end, use `c:\program files\java\jdk-18.0.2.1`